# Sonar rule: Tests should include assertions, assertEquals isn't reconized?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
....
@Test
public void testStdDevIsZeroWhenNoValues() {
    ContribPriceDiffCalculator priceDiffContrib = createPriceDiffContribWithoutEntries();
    Assert.assertEquals(0., priceDiffContrib.getStdDev(null, null), DELTA);
}
```

Sonar give me the alert : **Tests should include assertion - Add at least one assertion to this test case.**

[image]

I don't understand why I have this alert if there is an assertion on my method ?

Sonar Version 5.6.1 - LGPL v3

Comment: Maybe you use an `Assert` class sonar does not know of? Have  a look at the import statement for `Assert` if it is `org.junit.Assert`.